# How many bytes of English and Chinese characters take in java?

Tags: java, encoding, character

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class TestChar {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String cnStr = "龙";
        String enStr = "a";
        byte[] cnBytes = cnStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] enBytes = enStr.getBytes("UTF-8");

        System.out.println("bytes size of Chinese：" + cnBytes.length);
        System.out.println("bytes size of English：" + enBytes.length);

        //  in java, char takes two bytes, the question is: 
        char cnc = '龙'; // will '龙‘ take two or three bytes ?
        char enc = 'a'; // will 'a' take one or two bytes ?
    }
}
```

**Output** :

```
   bytes size of Chinese：3

   bytes size of English：1
```

Here, My JVM is set as UTF-8, from the output, we know Chinese character '龙' takes 3 bytes, and English character 'a' takes one byte. My question is:

In Java, char takes two bytes, here, char cnc = '龙'; char enc = 'a';  will cnc only takes two bytes instead of 3 bytes ? And 'a' takes two bytes instead of one byte ?

Answer (score 5):

The codepoint value of `龙` is 40857. That fits inside the two bytes of a char.

It takes 3 bytes to encode in UTF-8 because not all 2-byte sequences are valid in UTF-8.

Answer (score 3):

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a variable-length character encoding, where characters take up 1 to 4 bytes.

A Java `char` is 16 bits. See [3.1 Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.1) in the Java Language Specification to understand how exactly Java handles Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Strings/chars are UTF-16, so it'll be the same for both: Each char will be 16bits.

`byte[] cnBytes = cnStr.getBytes("UTF-8");`

UTF-8 is a variable length encoding, so the Chinese char takes more bits because it's out of the ASCII character range.

Comment: In recent versions, if all the characters in a string are Latin-1, Java can store them internally one byte per character, but that isn't really relevant to this question. A `char` is still always 16 bits.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that! It sounds like the old speed trick from yesteryear `-XX:UseCompressedStrings`