# Why reading a character that has no ASCII representation with System.in doesn't give the character in two bytes?

Tags: java, character-encoding, system.in

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        char ch = '诶';

        System.out.println((int)ch);

        int c;
        while ((c = System.in.read()) != -1)
        {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
35830
```

Here, The value that represents the char `诶` in unicode is `35830`. In binary, It'll be `10001011 11110110`.

When I enter that character in the terminal, I expected to get two bytes, `10001011` and `11110110`. and when combining them again, I can be able to obtain the original char.

But what I actually get is:

```
232
175
182
10
```

I can see that `10` represent the newline character. But what does the first 3 numbers mean?

Comment: I'm asking what do these three numbers represent? why didn't it just read the correspoding 2 bytes for the character?

Comment: Those three numbers are the UTF-8 representation of `诶`.

Comment: @dnault how is 232 175 182 related to 35830?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many bytes of English and Chinese characters take in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59039660/how-many-bytes-of-english-and-chinese-characters-take-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UTF-8 is a multi-byte variable-length encoding.

In order for something reading a stream of bytes to know that there are more bytes to be read in order to finish the current codepoint, there are some values that just cannot occur in a valid UTF-8 byte stream. Basically, certain patterns indicate "hang on, I'm not done".

There's a table which explains it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf-8#Description). For a codepoint in the range U+0800 to U+FFFF, it needs 16 bits to represent it; its byte representation consists of 3 bytes:

```
1st byte    2nd byte    3rd byte
1110xxxx    10xxxxxx    10xxxxxx
```

You are seeing `232 175 182` because those are the bytes of the UTF-8 encoding.

```
byte[] bytes = "诶".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (byte b : bytes) {
  System.out.println((0xFF & b) + " " + Integer.toString(0xFF & b, 2));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5wWQBm)

Output:

```
232 11101000
175 10101111
182 10110110
```

So the 3 bytes follow the pattern described above.

Comment: The UTF-8 bytes can also be seen here: [Unicode Han Character 'an exclamation of confirmation' (U+8BF6)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8bf6/index.htm)